# Submit Form with external submit button only if at least one Checkbox is checked

Tags: html, jquery, css, forms

I am making a add to cart program but I want to add particular product to cart with their selected attributes like size and colours. Since my submit button is not inside the form, I need to submit the form with Jquery only if at least one checkbox from the size form is selected else onclick of the cart button it should display the div `#tipdivcontent`. I am not able to understand where am I going wrong here.

**UPDATED FIDDLE LINK BECAUSE WRONG LINK WAS INSERTED**

The code is given below with the snippet and **[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/289uh013/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cartorcheckoutbutton').click(function () {
        var $form = $('#sizesform');
        var $checkbox = $('.roomselect');

        $form.on('submit', function (e) {
            if (!$checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                $('#tipdivcontent').css("display", "block");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#tipdivcontent
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Cart" class="cartorcheckoutbutton">
<form action="../cart" method="POST" id="sizesform">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Sizes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="2.2">2.2</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.2" name="size" value="twopointtwo">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="2.4">2.4</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.4" name="size" value="twopointfour">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="2.6">2.6</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.6" name="size" value="twopointsix">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="2.8">2.8</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.8" name="size" value="twopointeight">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <label for="2.10">2.10</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.10" name="size" value="twopointten">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="tipdivcontent">Please Select Size.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to submit your form like this.

We can trigger the `submit` event of the form in this way also.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.cartorcheckoutbutton').click(function (e) {
                var $form = $('#sizesform');
                var $checkbox = $('.roomselect');
                if (!$checkbox.is(':checked')) {
                    alert('Please confirm!');
                    $('#tipdivcontent').css("display", "block");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                else
                    $form.submit();
                
            });            
        });
```

```css
#tipdivcontent
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" value="Cart" class="cartorcheckoutbutton">
<form action="../cart" method="POST" id="sizesform">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Sizes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="2.2">2.2</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.2" name="size" value="twopointtwo">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="2.4">2.4</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.4" name="size" value="twopointfour">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="2.6">2.6</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.6" name="size" value="twopointsix">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="2.8">2.8</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.8" name="size" value="twopointeight">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                <label for="2.10">2.10</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="roomselect" type="checkbox" id="2.10" name="size" value="twopointten">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="tipdivcontent">Please Select Size.</div>
```

Comment: It gets submitted directly as per your script even if I don't check any checkbox

Comment: Now check my updated answer. It will trigger the submit event of form only if any `checkbox`  has been checked.

Comment: That's Perfectly what I was looking ahead for. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Put your button inside the form. Also, no need for the click event. Just use the submit event.

Comment: I can't put my submit button inside the form, because I've some other reasons for that so need to do it this way only.

Comment: Then your submit event will never fire.

Answer (score 1):

please try if this is working,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#cartorcheckoutbutton').click(function () {
    var $form = $('#sizesform');
    var $checkbox = $('.roomselect');     

        if(!$checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please confirm!');
            e.preventDefault();
        }else{
         $('form#sizesform').submit();
        }

  });
});
```

when i tried,it worked.

Comment: @hardik-sisodia,  try this.  i have edited my answer.